# Fullcalendar not rendering in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

Route:

```
Route::get('/calendar/{id}', 'TasksController@showcalendar')->name('cal');
```

Function:

```
    public function showcalendar($id)
{
    // $tasks = Task::where('halls_id', '=', '1')->get();
    return view('tasks.test');
}
```

test.blade.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
<h1>  Test</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

fullcalendar/main.css and main.js are both in the public/fullcalendar folder, using the newest library and literally just copy pasted what the website showed as an example... Honestly not sure what I am missing

Going to /calendar/1 it shows a blank page except for the H1 words "Test"

Using laravel 5.4.36

Comment: Add preceding '/' in both href and src like href="/fullcalendar/main.css" & src="/fullcalendar/main.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `{{ URL::asset() }}` while you called css and js

```
<link href='{{ URL::asset('fullcalendar/main.css') }}' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='{{ URL::asset('fullcalendar/main.js') }}'></script>
```